# How to convert type Row into Vector to feed to the KMeans

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, k-means, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-sql

when i try to feed df2 to kmeans i get the following error

```
clusters = KMeans.train(df2, 10, maxIterations=30,
                        runs=10, initializationMode="random")
```

The error i get:

```
Cannot convert type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.Row'> into Vector
```

df2 is a dataframe created as follow:

```
df = sqlContext.read.json("data/ALS3.json")
df2 = df.select('latitude','longitude')

df2.show()


     latitude|       longitude|

   60.1643075|      24.9460844|
   60.4686748|      22.2774728|
```

how can i convert this two columns to Vector and feed it to KMeans?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### ML

The problem is that you missed the [documentation's example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=kmeans#pyspark.ml.clustering.KMeans), and it's pretty clear that the method `train` requires a `DataFrame` with a `Vector` as features.

To modify your current data's structure you can use a [VectorAssembler](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=vectorassembler#pyspark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler). In your case it could be something like:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

vectorAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=["latitude", "longitude"],
                                  outputCol="features")

# For your special case that has string instead of doubles you should cast them first.
expr = [col(c).cast("Double").alias(c) 
        for c in vectorAssembler.getInputCols()]

df2 = df2.select(*expr)
df = vectorAssembler.transform(df2)
```

Besides, you should also normalize your `features` using the class [MinMaxScaler](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=vectorassembler#pyspark.ml.feature.MinMaxScaler) to obtain better results.

#### MLLib

In order to achieve this using `MLLib` you need to use a map function first, to convert all your `string` values into `Double`, and merge them together in a [DenseVector](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=densevector#pyspark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector).

```py
rdd = df2.map(lambda data: Vectors.dense([float(c) for c in data]))
```

After this point you can train your [MLlib's KMeans model](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=kmeans#pyspark.mllib.clustering.KMeans) using the `rdd` variable.

Answer (score 5):

I got **PySpark 2.3.1** to perform [KMeans](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=kmeans#pyspark.mllib.clustering.KMeans) on a [DataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame) as follows:

1. Write a list of the columns you want to include in the clustering analysis:

```py
feat_cols = ['latitude','longitude']`
```

2. You need all of the columns to be **numeric values**:

```py
expr = [col(c).cast("Double").alias(c) for c in feat_cols]
df2 = df2.select(*expr)
```

3. Create your **features** vector with `mllib.linalg.Vectors`:

```py
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=feat_cols, outputCol="features")
df3 = assembler.transform(df2).select('features')
```

4. You should **normalize your features** as normalization is not always required, but it rarely hurts ([more about this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777201/why-vector-normalization-can-improve-the-accuracy-of-clustering-and-classificati)):

```py
from pyspark.ml.feature import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler(
    inputCol="features",
    outputCol="scaledFeatures",
    withStd=True,
    withMean=False)
scalerModel = scaler.fit(df3)
df4 = scalerModel.transform(df3).drop('features')\
                     .withColumnRenamed('scaledFeatures', 'features')
```

5. Turn your [DataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame) object `df4` into a dense vector [RDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/mllib-data-types.html):

```py
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
data5 = df4.rdd.map(lambda row: Vectors.dense([x for x in row['features']]))
```

6. Use the obtained RDD object as input for KMeans training:

```py
from pyspark.mllib.clustering import KMeans
model = KMeans.train(data5, k=3, maxIterations=10)
```

7. Example: classify a point *p* in your vector space:

```py
prediction = model.predict(p)
```