# Converting Dataframe to Vector.dense for k-mean

Tags: scala, apache-spark, k-means

Following the answer to this question
[How to convert type Row into Vector to feed to the KMeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142973/how-to-convert-type-row-into-vector-to-feed-to-the-kmeans)

I have created the feature table for my data.(`assembler` is a Vector Assembler)

```
val kmeanInput  = assembler.transform(table1).select("features")
```

When I run k-means with `kmeanInput`

```
val clusters = KMeans.train(kmeanInput, numCluster, numIteration)
```

I get the error

> :102: error: type mismatch; found   : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame (which expands to)  org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector] val clusters = KMeans.train(kmeanInput, numCluster, numIteration)

As @Jed mentioned in his answer, this happens because rows are not in `Vectors.dense` format.
To solve this I tried

```
 val dat = kmeanInput.rdd.map(lambda row: Vectors.dense([x for x in 
 row["features"]]))
```

And I get this error

> :3: error: ')' expected but '(' found. val dat = kmeanInput.rdd.map(lambda row: Vectors.dense([x for x in row["features"]]))
>
> :3: error: ';' expected but ')' found. val dat = kmeanInput.rdd.map(lambda row: Vectors.dense([x for x in row["features"]]))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You imported the incorrect library, you should use `KMeans` from `ml` instead of `mllib`. The first one uses a `DataFrame` and the second one uses an `RDD`.