# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "features" does not exist

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "features" does not exist.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.scala:264)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.apply(StructType.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.SchemaUtils$.checkColumnType(SchemaUtils.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeansParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(KMeans.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans.validateAndTransformSchema(KMeans.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans.transformSchema(KMeans.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans.fit(KMeans.scala:304)
    at sparkExample.spExample.ClusteringDSPOC.main(ClusteringDSPOC.java:45)
17
```

My code is

```
package sparkExample.spExample;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans;
import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeansModel;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

public class ClusteringDSPOC {

    private static final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile(" ");
    private static final SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkJdbcDs").setMaster("local[*]"));
    private static final String POSTGRESQL_DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";
    private static final String POSTGRESQL_USERNAME = "xyz";
    private static final String POSTGRESQL_PWD = "xyz";
    private static final String POSTGRESQL_CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.111.130:5432/xyzdb?user=" + POSTGRESQL_USERNAME + "&password=" + POSTGRESQL_PWD;
    private static final String POSTGRESQL_TABLE = "(select id, duration from abc where duration is not null ) as abc";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //Datasource options
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("JavaKMeansExample").getOrCreate();
        Class.forName(POSTGRESQL_DRIVER);  
        Properties options = new Properties();
        Dataset<Row> sdrDS = spark.read().format("libsvm").jdbc(POSTGRESQL_CONNECTION_URL, POSTGRESQL_TABLE, options);

        Dataset<Row> durationDS = sdrDS.select("duration");


        KMeans kmeans = new KMeans().setK(2).setSeed(1L);
        KMeansModel model = kmeans.fit(durationDS);
    }
}
```

I am following this
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-clustering.html.

Getting this error while fit method is called.Please help me on fixing this or else some alternate option to do this.Thanks

Here I am trying to devide duration into 2 to 3 clusters and then map cluster with id.Same thing I am able to do by using Spark mllib library in this way

```
package sparkExample.spExample;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;

public class ClusteringPOC1 {

    private static final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile(" ");
    private static final JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkJdbcDs").setMaster("local[*]"));
    private static final String POSTGRESQL_DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";
    private static final String POSTGRESQL_USERNAME = "abc";
    private static final String POSTGRESQL_PWD = "abc";
    private static final String POSTGRESQL_CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.111.130:5432/abcdb?user=" + POSTGRESQL_USERNAME + "&password=" + POSTGRESQL_PWD;

    private static final SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //Datasource options
        Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();
        options.put("driver", POSTGRESQL_DRIVER);
        options.put("url", POSTGRESQL_CONNECTION_URL);
        options.put("dbtable", "(select id, duration from sdr_log where duration is not null ) as sdr_log");
        Dataset<Row> sdrDF = sqlContext.load("jdbc", options);
        JavaRDD<Row> sdrData = sdrDF.toJavaRDD();
        sdrData.cache();
        JavaRDD<Vector> durationData = sdrData.map(row -> {
            double value = new Double(row.get(2).toString());
            return Vectors.dense(value);
        });
        durationData.cache();

        KMeansModel clusters = KMeans.train(durationData.rdd(), numClusters, numIterations);
        JavaRDD<Integer> clusterLabel =  clusters.predict(durationData);
        JavaRDD<Long> id = sdrData.map(row -> new Long(row.get(1).toString()));
        JavaPairRDD<Long, Integer> clusterLableData = id.zip(clusterLabel);
        clusterLableData.saveAsTextFile("data/mlib/kmeans_output11.txt");

    }
}
```

But I want to do this with spark ml library.

Answer (score 0):

K-means is an unsupervised clustering algorithm that tries to partition a set of points into K sets (clusters) such that the points in each cluster tend to be near each other.

> ```
>     Dataset<Row> durationDS = sdrDS.select("duration");
> ```

In your code, you are iterating over row while selecting a single column 'durations' and you're setting the number of clusters as 2. But how can you classify the data into clusters when you are having no basis to do so?

The essence of unsupervised learning algorithms, in this case the Kmeans, is that you are not needed to specify parameters relating to logic of the dataset while using it. You are just needed to pass (fit) the dataset in the model and it classifies it into clusters.

In the K-means algorithm, the model tries to find the K-nearest neighbour. It needs some data to classify the cluster, whereas you're passing a single column.

It is better to use the Spark's Dataframe API to resolve the error you are facing.
Spark automatically reads the schema from the MySQL table and maps its types back to Spark SQL’s types

Import into a Dataframe object

```
> DataFrame jdbcDF= sql.Context.read().format("libsvm").jdbc(POSTGRESQL_CONNECTION_URL,POSTGRESQL_TABLE, options);
```

You can now drop columns you don't want using the DF.drop('ColumnName') function.
Or/And fit your dataset this way..

```
> KMeansModel model = kmeans.fit(jdbcDF);
```

Also, It would be great if you could provide the dataset

Comment: Hi Akshat Thank you for your response. but I am using 2.1.0 version there is no DataFrame class.And In my code if I am using KMeansModel model = kmeans.fit(sdrDS) instead of KMeansModel model = kmeans.fit(durationDS) also getting the same issue.

Comment: Also if i am going to older version 1.6.3  and doing the way you approached I am getting this exception Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'features' given input columns: [duration];

Comment: sdrDS.show(); gives +---------+--------+
|       id|duration|
+---------+--------+
|170359216|  10.225|
|171133923|  10.008|
|171133924|  10.002|
|171133925|  10.010|
|170359219|  10.228|
|170423864|   5.106|
|170423865|   5.106|
|170423866|   5.106|
|170423867|   5.104|
|170423868|   5.105|
|170423869|   5.104|
|170423870|   5.104|
|170423871|   5.105|
|170423872|   5.104|
|170423873|   5.106|
|170423874|   5.103|
|170423875|   5.106|
|170423876|   5.106|
|170423877|   5.103|
|170423878|   5.107|
+---------+--------+

Comment: durationDs.show() gives +--------+
|duration|
+--------+
|  10.225|
|  10.008|
|  10.002|
|  10.010|
|  10.228|
|   5.106|
|   5.106|
|   5.106|
|   5.104|
|   5.105|
|   5.104|
|   5.104|
|   5.105|
|   5.104|
|   5.106|
|   5.103|
|   5.106|
|   5.106|
|   5.103|
|   5.107|
+--------+ and both contains column names

Comment: JavaRDD<Row> sdrDS = spark.read().format("libsvm").jdbc(POSTGRESQL_CONNECTION_URL, POSTGRESQL_TABLE, options);                                                    StructField[] fields = {new StructField("features", new VectorUDT(), false, Metadata.empty())};
    StructType schema = new StructType(fields);
    DataFrame dataset = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sdrDS, schema);             Try this. The model is trying to find the features column which you explicitly have to make in this case.

Comment: Dataset class is essentially performing the same functions. Use it if you shall. Just don't select a specific column when you are just having 2 columns, as it can be seen from your dataset

Comment: I have to apply k-means on duration column only, that's why I am selecting that.And as per https://fossies.org/diffs/spark/1.6.2_vs_2.0.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/ml/JavaKMeansExample.java-diff.html if we are going for dataset we don't need to all these manually.Can you give me a way to fix this by using datasets not dataframe..

Comment: Hi Ambuj. I cannot seem to find any correlation that K-means would find in your dataset. It would be nice if you can tell me what are you trying to achieve through your data set. Since then, I would be able to help you better. Also, refer to this for some clarity https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142973/how-to-convert-type-row-into-vector-to-feed-to-the-kmeans

Comment: Hi Akshat I have edited the description because I can't add much code here.Please check.

Comment: Let us think I am having durations varies from 0 to 20 and I choosed 2 clusters. So I will get 2 clusters center let us 5 and 15 and 2 clusters with duration like 0-10 and 11-20. And i want to identify which id comes under which cluster. This one I am able to do with spark mllib but I want now this with spark ml and datasets.Please help

Comment: Hi. Try renaming your column 'duration' to features and fitting it into the model. Even though the model requires your features column to be an vector, let me know what error you encounter.

Comment: I found another way like QuantileDiscretizer discretizer = new QuantileDiscretizer() .setInputCol("duration")
      .setOutputCol("result")
      .setNumBuckets(3);
discretizer.fit(sdrDS).transform(sdrDS).show();  but my duration column type coming from database is bigdecimal. so i am getting error like     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Column duration must be of type DoubleType but was actually DecimalType(8,3).at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
Can you help in this

Comment: Hi Ambuj. Why don't you just cast your duration column as Double with the help of the Scala function toDouble?

Comment: Hi Akshat, I am getting a dataset here Dataset<Row> sdrDS = spark.read().jdbc(POSTGRESQL_CONNECTION_URL, POSTGRESQL_TABLE, options); can u please give me an example how to do this in java.