# scaling inputs data to neural network

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

Do we have to scale input data for neural network? How does it affect the final solution of neural network?

I've tried to find some reliable sources on that. The book "elements of statistical learning" (page 400) says it will help choosing reasonable initial random weights to start with.

Aren't the final weights deterministic regardless of the initial random weights we use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Firstly, there are many types of ANNs, I will assume you are talking about the simplest one - multilayer perceptron with backpropagation.

Secondly, in your question you are mixing up data scaling (normalization) and weight initialization.

You need to randomly initialize *weights* to avoid symmetry while learning (if all weights are initially the same, their update will also be the same). In general, concrete values don't matter, but too large values can cause slower convergence.

You are not *required* to normalize your *data*, but normalization can make learning process faster. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674623/why-do-we-have-to-normalize-the-input-for-an-artificial-neural-network) for more details.