# Is it important for a neural network to have normally distributed data?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, neural-network, normalization, normal-distribution

So one of the standard things to do with the data is normalize it and standardize it to have data that's normally distributed with a mean 0 and standard deviation of 1, right? But, what if the data is NOT normally distributed?

Also, does the desired output has to be normally distributed too? What if I want my feedforward net to classify between two classes (-1, and 1), that would be impossible to standardize into a normal distribution of mean 0 and std of 1 right?

Feedforward nets are non-parametric right?  So if they are, is it still important to standarize data? And why do people standarize it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we have to normalize the input for an artificial neural network?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674623/why-do-we-have-to-normalize-the-input-for-an-artificial-neural-network)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Standardizing the features isn't to make the data fit a normal distribution, it's to put the feature values in a known range that makes it easier for algorithms to learn from the data. This is because most algorithms are not scale/shift invariant. Decision Trees, for example, are both scale and shift invariant, and so doing the normalization has no impact on the performance of the tree.

> Also, does the desired output has to be normally distributed too?

No. That's not a thing. The output is whatever the output is. You do have to make sure the activation function of the final layer of your network can make the predictions you want (i.e.: Sigmoid activation can't output negative values or values > 1).

> Feedforward nets are non-parametric right?

No, they would generally be considered parametric. Parametric / non-parametric doesn't really have a hard definition. People may mean slightly different things when talking about this.

> So if they are, is it still important to standardize data?

Those things have nothing to do with each other at all.

> And why do people standardize it?

That's the very first thing I mention, it's to make learning easier/possible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. On your point you mentioned the use of standardization to make sure inputs fall within a specific range. But I have read some people use standardization to make sure the inputs/outputs have mean 0 and a uniform variance (even if they already are within a range). Why?

Comment: I just answered why. Its to make optimization/learning easier. Or to put the output in the range that the activation function can actually reach.