# Can a neural network have integer inputs?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I build a neural network with input as a mixture of integers and booleans. But it did not converge. I have seen many examples on internet and every one of them has input in boolean form. So is it possible to build a neural network with a mixture of inputs or integer inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, it is. What you probability need to do is to **normalize** your inputs. This means that you could divide a feature's value by the maximum value you expect to see in that place, so that everything lies in the range (-1,1).

Some links to understand normalization of inputs:
[Why do we have to normalize the input for an artificial neural network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674623/why-do-we-have-to-normalize-the-input-for-an-artificial-neural-network)
https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_normalize_input_and_output_data_in_training_neural_networks

Another recent way to ensure normalization is the concept of [batch normalization](https://gist.github.com/shagunsodhani/4441216a298df0fe6ab0)