# How to load a 3D array with mixed data types into Tensorflow for training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, data-science

I am working with a dataset that looks something like this-

```
PERSON1 = [["Person1Id", "Rome", "Frequent Flyer", "1/2/2018"],["Person1Id", "London", "Frequent Flyer", "3/4/2018"],["Person1Id", "Paris", "Frequent Flyer", "2/4/2018"], ...]
PERSON2 = [["Person2Id", "Shenzen", "Frequent Flyer", "1/2/2018"],["Person2Id", "London", "Frequent Flyer", "2/6/2018"],["Person2Id", "Hong Kong", "Not Frequent Flyer", "1/3/2017"], ...]
PERSON3 = [["Person3Id", "Moscow", "Frequent Flyer", "1/2/2018"],["Person3Id", "London", "Frequent Flyer", "3/4/2018"],["Person3Id", "Paris", "Frequent Flyer", "2/4/2018"], ...]
...

TRAIN_X = [ 
    PERSON1, PERSON2, PERSON3, ..., PERSONN
]

TRAIN_Y = [
    1, 0, 1, ..., 1
]
```

The idea being that some persons are of class `1` and some of class `0`, depending on training data. (The actual data arrays utilized are longer, this is a simplified version.)

My question is - given this structure of data - how might I correctly load it into Tensorflow to train a neural network system? I've worked with simpler datasets like the Iris dataset, MNIST, etc. I have no idea how to deal with more complex, real-world data like this, and I can't seem to find any documentation / resources / sample code that does anything similar.

I assume the first step here is that the data needs to be flattened, normalized, etc - in some way, however, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I am not sure that using neural network classifiers would be the best way to do this (maybe you should consider using network theory and/or hybrid approaches).
However, one possibility might be to map each of those literal vectors into numbers: is it possible? For example: each city can be associated to a pair of numbers indicating the geographical coordinates (so that you can define distances among places). If you could do something like that for all the fields you would be able to define a vector of numbers to be fed into your neural network (i.e. a multilayer perceptron)

Comment: As suggested in the given answer, you need to do some preprocessing. First, you must decide what inputs you will give to your model. For example, using city names as categories is reasonable, although you could also use their latitude and longitude. Then you have to decide how you put these as numbers for the neural network, using one-hot, embeddings, buckets, etc. You can do this out- or in-graph. Have a look at [Feature Columns](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/feature_columns) to see a way in which TensorFlow may support you with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do some heavier preprocessing for that data. Neural networks can't work with text data directly, so you need to do some embedding.

Based on the type of your feature vector you will probably want to do some type of encoding of data to numbers [by onehot or label encoding](https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-one-hot-encode-data-in-machine-learning/), or transformation to geographical coordinates, if it makes sense for the task.

You'll probably use one-hot encoding for city names, since they are categorical data, but you'll want to transform ordinal data, like date, to numbers. 
And think which data are useful for the task. E.g. if the problem you want to solve using NN utilizes the person ID or not.

Also, you will probably have tensors of different shapes after the input processing, so it might be better to split the input into multiple variables (e.g. if you had some features encoded as one-hot, and some not).

Also remember that you'll need to [normalize inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674623/why-do-we-have-to-normalize-the-input-for-an-artificial-neural-network) to the network, so choose the representation accordingly.

I'm afraid there is no plug'n'play solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have categorical data. And let's assume that's how you want it to be.

You can either pre-process it in pure python if this makes sense given your amount of data (for instance, run your pre-processing once and save the preprocessed data instead of re-processing everytime). This would mean having something like:

```py
import numpy as np

def one_hot(index, max_dim):
    return np.eye(max_dim)[index]

destinations = {
    "Moscow": 0,
    "London": 1,
    # etc.
}
one_hot_destinations = {
    k: one_hot(v, len(destinations)) 
    for k, v in destinations.items()
}
def process_loc(loc):
    return one_hot_destinations[loc]

# do some similar processing to other properties of a "PERSON"
# so that you represent them in a vector / scalar way then:

def process_person(person_item):
    pid, loc, status, date = person
    return np.concatenate(
        [
            process_pid(pid), 
            process_loc(loc), 
            process_status(status), 
            process_date(date)
        ],
        axis=0)

TRAIN_X = [[process_person(item) for item in p] for p in PERSONS]
```

Or you can process it in C++ on the fly with tensorflow
So what you can do is do a [`table_lookup`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/lookup/index_table_from_file) which is much like looking into a dictionary:

```
dictionary = tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_file(dictionary, num_oov_buckets=0)
```

You have to understand that given the amount of context and code you have given it is hard to help you further than Matěj Račinský and I have tried to do. We have no clue what your down stream task is for instance.

If you want to do something NLP-related, maybe you can have a look at the blog post I wrote a few months back: [Multi-label Text Classification with Tensorflow](https://vict0rs.ch/2018/06/17/multilabel-text-classification-tensorflow/) which includes the data pre-processing with `table_lookup`