# Why the pendulum in openai gym has cos and sin feature? why not just use one of them?

Tags: python, openai-gym, pendulum

Why the pendulum has cos and sin feature? Can I just use 1 of them? Or can I use theta (the angle) instead?

I expect some explanation for this XD, intuitive or theoretical ones are all welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The angles(thetas) are passed through the sin() and cos() function so that the observations are in the range [-1,1]. This fixed range of [-1,1] helps in stabilising the training in the neural networks which has been explained well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674623/why-do-we-have-to-normalize-the-input-for-an-artificial-neural-network).

You could even use one of the sin() or cos() as your observation. The reason(which I can think of) for using both sin() and cos() is probably to give more information about the state. Maybe using both sin() and cos() leads to a faster convergence.

But normalisation of the inputs is necessary. So, you cannot just use the angles as your state observations for training.

Edit: Answer to the comment by @CHEN TIANRONG
[image: Plots]

I ran DDPG with just sin() and theta_dot in one experiment and with sin(), cos() and theta_dot in another experiment. Clearly the agent never learns the task in the first experiment.

The usage of both sin() and cos() is experimental I guess.

You can find the code I used for the experiments [here](https://github.com/nsidn98/Stack-Overflow/tree/master/Pendulum_states).

Improving the rate of convergence of a neural network for RL agents is an active area of research. You could search for algorithms which are sample efficient. For example: [Sample-Efficient Reinforcement Learning with Stochastic Ensemble Value Expansion](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.01675), [Sample Efficient Actor-Critic with Experience Replay](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.01224), etc.

Comment: Awesome answer. You said the If we use two of them, it will lead to relatively fast convergence? How do you get this point? I mean.... how can I find out some way to accelerate the convergence of neural network, just as you said, more features. Are there any papers explain that?

Comment: Answered your question in the comment in the edits.

Comment: What a good answer! Thanks! I will check these two paper later. Thanks!!!