# Understanding input and output of tflite model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, inference

I am brand new to Tensorflow and trying to incorporate it into my project. I am using a raspberry pi4 with a camera to detect change from my bird feeder, take a picture, and then identify that bird with tensorflow. I am using the [Birds_V1](https://tfhub.dev/google/aiy/vision/classifier/birds_V1/1) to accomplish this.

I am curious as to how to interpret the input and output. According to the overview the input is:

> expected to be 3-channel RGB color images of size 224 x 224, scaled to [0, 1].

I am confused by what is meant by scaled to [0,1]
Furthermore, the output

> image_classifier: A probability vector of dimension 965, corresponding to a background class and 964 bird species in the labelmap.

I am completely lost by what is meant here.

Lastly, I ran interpreter.get_input_details() and interpreter.get_output_details()  to see what it would output to me.

I got this printed back, with the top being the input and bottom the output:

```
[{'name': 'module/hub_input/images_uint8', 'index': 170, 'shape': array([  1, 224, 224,   3]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.uint8'>, 'quantization': (0.0078125, 128), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([0.0078125], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([128]), 'quantized_dimension': 0}}]

[{'name': 'module/prediction', 'index': 171, 'shape': array([  1, 965]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.uint8'>, 'quantization': (0.00390625, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([0.00390625], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([0]), 'quantized_dimension': 0}}]
```

I don't know how to interpret this, and was wondering if I should be going off of this instead or ignoring it if its not important.

I appreciate any clarification that can be given to any part of this, and appreciate any sources that you may deem useful for solving this. I have looked for focumentation for help, but haven't gotten anywhere yet.

Comment: Hi, think of scaling as a mathematical operation to bring the values into the range [0,1]. For example MinMaxScaler (subtract minimum from a value and divide by the difference between the minimum and maximum). Each training output would give a probability vector of size 965  that an image A, belongs to any of the 965 classes. Then you pick the highest probability value as the true bird species. For example in a 5 species model output1 = [0.1,0.1,0.6, 0.1, 0.1] corresponding to [A,B,C,D,E] species respectively. This would mean the input image is classified as species C(highest value 0.6).

Comment: @smile Hi, thanks for commenting. So if I'm understanding what you're saying, I need to use some function like MInMaxScaler to scale the probability value for each of the potential 965 labels to be some number between 0 and 1, with all of the probabilities totaling up to 1?

Comment: You scale the input (the images). The probability vector are what the model returns. You do not need to scale that. The probability vector  tells you in probabilistic terms what species the input belongs. I hope this helps.

Comment: Ya, that makes sense. Thank you, I appreciate your help. I at least understand that part of my question now!

Comment: To the last part of your question. First you are using pretrained model from Tensorhub https://blog.tensorflow.org/2018/03/introducing-tensorflow-hub-library.html . On the tensorhub page, you can browse available modules (your example is from classification examples). One could observe your example is also a TFLite pre-trained module, so this https://www.tensorflow.org/lite would be particularly useful. This https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/image_classification/overview contains image classification details for TFLite. The links contain lots of info.  Explore them. Best regards

Comment: @smile Hi again. I have been looking at the tensorflow.org/lite docs. I'll give the 2nd link you send a try as well, as it seems very helpful for my topic. Thanks for the help again!

Comment: I am glad it helped. Best regards !

Answer (score 1):

Most of the questions are answered by @smile in the comments but providing the Clarifications here (Answer Section) for the benefit of the Community.

**Question**: I am confused by what is meant by scaled to [0,1]

**Answer**: Usually, the `Images` are nothing but a `Numpy Array` (in your case of shape 224, 224, 3) whose values range from `0 to 255`. We `Normalize` the `Pixel Values` by dividing each Pixel Value by 255 so that value of every `Pixel` will be in range `[0,1]`. If we don't `Normalize` the `Pixel Values`, time taken for the `Model` to `Converge` will be very high.

For more information regarding Normalization please refer this [Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4674770/11530462) and this [Stack Exchange Answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/185857).

**Question**: A `probability vector` of dimension 965, corresponding to a background `class` and 964 bird species in the label map. I am completely lost by what is meant here.

**Answer**: In the Final Layer of our CNN, we will be using a `Softmax Activation Function` with the `Number of Units` equal to `Number of Classes` (in your case, its value is **965**). So, the `Output` of that `Layer` will result in the 965 `Probabilities` with the sum of all the `Probabilities` being 1. The `Class` with highest `Probability` represents the `Class` corresponding to that `Image`.

For example in a 5 species `model output = [0.1,0.1,0.6, 0.1, 0.1]` corresponding to `[A,B,C,D,E]` species respectively. This would mean the input image is classified as species C(highest value 0.6). (have taken @smile's example, as it is explained well).

**Question**: I don't know how to interpret `interpreter.get_input_details` and `interpreter.get_output_details`

**Answer**: The Source Code of [get_input_details](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.2.0/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter.py#L380-L388) explains that it **returns A list of all the details of our Input Image Tensor**. Similarly, the Source code of [get_output_details](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.2.0/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter.py#L423-L431) explains that it **returns A list of all the details of our Output Prediction Tensor**. Information about the API, Interpreter can be found in this [Tensorflow Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/Interpreter).

So in the code,

```
[{'name': 'module/hub_input/images_uint8', 'index': 170, 

'shape': array([  1, 224, 224,   3]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.uint8'>, 

'quantization': (0.0078125, 128), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': 

array([0.0078125], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([128]), 

'quantized_dimension': 0}}]
```

`Name` indicates the `Name` of the Input Tensor in the Graph, `Shape` indicates its `shape`. The purpose of `Quantization` is to reduce the Size of the `Model` as the `Memory` of `Mobile Devices` will be less. More Information about the `Quantization` can be found in this [Tensorflow Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/model_optimization#quantization).